# What's wrong with my iOS sqlite delete method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am making a sqlite for iOS. I have succeeded to save data and present, but not delete.
This is my createTable Method:

```
- (void) createTable: (NSString *) tableName
          withField1: (NSString *) field1
          withField2: (NSString *) field2
          withField3: (NSString *) field3
          withField4: (NSString *) field4{
    char *err;
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '%@' ('%@' "
                     "TEXT PRIMARY KEY, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT);", tableName, field1,field2,field3,field4];

    if(sqlite3_exec(db,[sql UTF8String], NULL,NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Could not create table");
     } else {
        NSLog(@"table created");
    }
}
```

This is my saveData method:

```
-(void) saveNewData :(NSString*)nickname :(NSString*)url :(NSString*)uid :(NSString*)pswd{


    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *sql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO accountListDB ('nickname', 'url',  'uid', 'pswd') VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%@', '%@')", nickname, url, uid, pswd];

        const char *insert_stmt = [sql UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"data added");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"failed to added");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
}
```

This is my deleteData method, which is not working:

```
-(void) deleteData:(NSString*)nickname :(NSString*)url :(NSString*)uid :(NSString*)pswd{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *sql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM accountListDB WHERE nickname = %@", nickname];

        const char *delete_stmt = [sql UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, delete_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"data deleted");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"failed to delete");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
}
```

It returns failed to delete.

Comment: What's the output of `filePath`?

Comment: [self filePath] returns documentsDirectory/db.sql

Comment: Don't build queries with `stringWithFormat:`. Properly bind values into the prepared statement.

Comment: And do better error checking. You must always check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. Use `sqlite3_errmsg` to log database errors.

Comment: Thank you rmaddy. You are right. I learnt this from a tutorial. I will follow your instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put `single quote` between your nickename in the query because if it contain space inside that it will not delete the records. Change your delete statement like this

```
 NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM accountListDB WHERE nickname = '%@'", nickname];
```

Comment: This will fail if the nickname contains a `'` character. Don't build queries with `stringWithFormat:`. Properly bind the value into the prepared statement.